# VS Code Intellisense can't find function called 'debug'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working on a Remix JS project, and in order to debug I have to export a function called 'debug'.

However, for some reason VSCode's intellisense can't find it. It offers this:
[image]

if I enter another function exported from the same module it finds it without problems:[image]

Here is the module I'm importing from:

```js
export function debug() {
    return;
}

export function hello() {
    return "hi";
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening...
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the issue.

You need to install `@types/debug` and `@types/react`. VS Code doesn't like .js or .jsx projects without those packages.

And my .jsconfig needed to look like this:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "checkJs": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "public",
        "netlify"
    ]
}
```